# Font Styling changing when clicked

Tags: html, css

I just bought a WordPress theme an tweaking it slightly, On the main Nav, The Portfolio like when first click goes bold then to normal weight, when I click any of the other 3 links the text goes normal then bold.

http://adamhuxtable.com

I want the styling to have a normal weight of font at all times.

I've had a look through the css and am unable to find anywhere that would make it behave like this.

Using Chrome on Mac.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: It's not bold, just changed background and foreground color, which is also happening on hover.

Comment: yeah,that's not fonweight=bold,and this effect is like "Mouseentr" or "Mousemove".These effects usually are in jQuery files and if you want to disable search in ".js" files.